# How can i use Embed Value with "<code>" in discord bot

Tags: discord.py

Im sorry before, but this possible to showing value embed discord as code, if in php  `and` , if on json, i can use :

````
{
    "name": "SOMETEXT",
    "value": "```ARGS ```"
},
````

and showing:

[image]

can i use in python to ? like `value=``` arg3 ``

```
embed.add_field(name='SOMETEXT', value=arg3, inline=False)
```

thanks advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in python just like :

````py
arg3 = "```Some markdown```"
embed = discord.Embed(title = "Test")
embed.add_field(name = "Test field", value = arg3, inline = False)

await ctx.send(embed = embed)
````

You can also directly pass the string to the value parameter :

````py
embed.add_field(name = "Test", value = "```Some markdown```", inline = False)
````

Next time try and see ;)